# Access attribute value from another attribute in React

Tags: reactjs, attributes

I have a `React` component for which I need to access an attribute from other attributes.

The use-case is having one of the attributes uniquely identify the component (`controlId`). The `value` attribute needs that id to know what to display from `props`, and the `onChange` attribute needs that id to tell the parent component how to update.

Currently, I can hardcode the Id in all three places.

```
<Input
    controlId={"someName"}
    value={this.props.fieldData["someName"]}
    onChange={(evnt) => this.props.handleFieldUpdate(evnt, "someName")}
/>
```

I have many components like this, and hardcoding strings like `"someName"` in multiple places is tedious and error prone. Is there a way to access the `controlId` attribute from the `onChange` and `value` attributes?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: Do you have to do it that way? Can't `name` and `value` get their values from the same state/props?

Comment: @HemadriDasari updated the description for my exact use-case

Comment: Yes you can using event <Input controlId={"some_name"} onChange={(e) => this.props.someFunc(e.target.controlId)}/>

Comment: @stever I am trying to uniquely identify each component

Answer (score 1):

Use event.target To access the properties of an element.
In your case to access controlId you can use event.target.controlId

```
   <Input controlId={"some_name"} onChange={event => this.props.someFunc(event.target.controlId)}/>
```

Comment: With `onChange` I can utilize the `event` object. Are there any similar such mechanisms for other attributes like `value`?

Comment: You can use document.getElementById or refs in react

Comment: Using `document.getElementById` will still result in using that Id in multiple places in the same component. I'm not sure how refs can be used here.